Can I prevent users from creating new organizations in CKAN?
We are using a CKAN deployment to host a data Catalogue and we started by creating an organization to host all of our datasets. I'd like all users of my company to create datasets under that same organization, however, it appears that any registered user can create new organizations in CKAN.
Is there a way to limit the creation of new organizations in CKAN? Perhaps by limiting that capability only to site admins?

You can limit organization and groups creation or deletion in CKAN to site admins by setting the ckan.auth.user_* options to false in your production.ini file:
ckan.auth.user_create_organizations = false
ckan.auth.user_create_groups = false
ckan.auth.user_delete_organizations = false
ckan.auth.user_delete_groups = false

After making this change, restart the CKAN service to apply the new setting.
